# Tracking camera movement using built-in accelerometer

Tags: tracking

Are there any apps that allow recording smartphone motion while shooting in order to move camera without point tracking?  And then, how to link this data to camera in scene?

Comment: read: https://medium.com/@JohnCoatesDev/visualizing-an-ios-device-in-blender-through-quantum-entanglement-ba8b6f0b47a5